# Razor for ASP.NET WebPages and IIS

Tags: iis, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I'm trying out ASP.NET webpages using the razor syntax so I created a sample site.  If I view the site in WebMatrix or using VisualStudio (view in browser) everything works fine.  When I try to create an IIS site I get a 404 error when trying to access any .cshtml files.  Regular html files work from the site.  It's set to .net 4 integrated.  I googled for an hour with no luck.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Please add the web.config to your question. There are some tricky differences between IIS and the ASP.NET development server when it comes to interpreting this configuration file.

Comment: Is this a local instance of IIS running on your own machine? If it's remote, then does it have ASP.NET WebPages installed?

Comment: When you say that you get a 404 requesting .cshtml files, are you including the file extension as part of the request? (e.g., mysite/app/test.chstml versus just mysite/app/test)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have just copied the files of your MVC application into a directory (or virtual directory) of IIS?

In order for your ASP.NET MVC application to work, you need to configure a web application in the IIS manager (right-click on "Default Web Site" and choose "Add application"). Then deploy your application to the just created application directory.

Comment: It's not an MVC application...ASP.NET WebPages.  And it is supposed to be at the root of the site not a subfolder.

Comment: IIS still needs to know that its an application (vs static content) so it can send to the .NET Runtime.  Try "add application" and associate with an app pool that is set to .NET 4 Integrated

Comment: The root directory should be an application by default, though I don't know how you can check that. But I agree with Taylor: you need to have .NET 4 registered in IIS (run aspnet_regiis from the .NET 4 directory) and it needs to be in integrated (and not in classic) mode. Also check that you have <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> in web.config.

Comment: I have several other .net 4 integrated sites running fine...But I reran aspnet_regiis...no luck.  Also I do have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true.

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same problem at my company.  To get it to work, we had to do a full .Net 4 install and the pages are being served correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if ".cshtml" is mapped correctly within the site's

Properties -> Home Directory -> Configuration... -> Mappings

Mine is mapped to:

c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

Answer (score 0):

This is a top hit for razor pages not working for .NET core or .NET 5 sites too.

I like to run my local development in IIS as it mirrors production. When setting up a new project, I set it up in IIS like normal but get a 404. All prerequisites are installed, I even have other .NET 5 razorpage sites running, so know it's a project setting.

Fix for me is to edit Properties\launchSettings.json (or edit via the GUI Project > ProjectNameHere Properties > Debug tab)

remove all profiles except one named after my project "ProjectNameHere"
Have the following settings:

```
  "commandName": "IIS",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
  "applicationUrl": "https://dev.projectnamehere.com"
```

1. Then save and press F5 or the Debug button in the toolbar.
2. Website will now work on https://dev.projectnamehere.com
3. Stop debugging
4. Hit https://dev.projectnamehere.com like a normal site
5. make razor page changes, refresh browser page like normal, see changes

Note: I edit my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to add `127.0.0.1 dev.projectnamehere.com` and use an online tool to create a self signed TLS cert for the domain which I install, to get all that working like production.